# Oracle applying count function with different conditon on Grouped Data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below SQL query

```
  SELECT 
  max (bt.NAME) "Batch Type",
  max(st.name) "Submission Status",
  count(sce.CLIP_POINT)--where sce.ACODE is not null
  ,count(sce.CLIP_POINT)--where sce.ACODE is null
  ,sum(sce.CLIP_POINT)--where sce.ACODE is not null
  ,sum(sce.CLIP_POINT)--where sce.ACODE is null
  from SUBMISSION_DATA_ENTRY sde,
  BATCH_PROCESSOR bp, status st,SUBMISSION_CLIP_ENTRY sce,
  SUBMISSION_PERIOD sp,BATCH_TYPE bt
  where sde.sub_perd_id=sp.sub_perd_id 
  and sde.bpr_pk=bp.bpr_pk and sde.sts_pk=st.sts_pk
  and sce.sde_pk=sde.sde_pk 
  and bt.bat_pk =bp.bat_pk
  group by bt.bat_pk, st.sts_pk;
```

Here I need to apply two count one for sce.ACODE is not null and one for other where
sce.ACODE is null.
How I can count the same column with different condition.
Please help

```
Edit
```

How to sum the same column with different condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SELECT:

To count nulls:

```
count (case when sce.acode is null then 1 else null end)
```

To count non-nulls:

```
count(sce.acode)
```

**EDIT**
Based on comment below, requirement is to sum clip_point, so:

```
-- sum of clip_point when acode is null
sum(case when sce.acode is null then sce.clip_point else 0 end)

 -- sum of clip_point when acode is not null 
sum(case when sce.acode is null then 0 else sce.clip_point end)
```

Comment: +1, but `ELSE NULL` is redundant, as `NULL` is the default of an un-satisfied `CASE`

Comment: @GoatCO True... but a CASE WHEN without an ELSE makes me itch.

Comment: Thank you your solution worked, But I need to apply a sum also like sum(case when sce.acode is null then sce.CLIP_POINT  else 0 end)
  ,sum(case when sce.acode is not null then sce.CLIP_POINT else 0 end) then I am getting the same result for both ,how to solve it ?

Comment: It will produce the same result.. you are counting the number of rows.  Unless I'm misunderstanding what you want a sum of.

Comment: I want to sum the sce.CLIP_POINT on the condition of sce.acode is null or not null

Comment: it's working now, It's the problem with the table data having same sum value

Answer (score 1):

How about using a sum?:

> ```
> SELECT 
>   max (bt.NAME) "Batch Type",
>   max(st.name) "Submission Status",
>   sum(case when sce.CLIP_POINT is not null then 1 else 0 end)--where sce.ACODE is not null
>   ,sum(case when sce.CLIP_POINT is null then 1 else 0 end)--where sce.ACODE is null
>   from SUBMISSION_DATA_ENTRY sde,
>   BATCH_PROCESSOR bp, status st,SUBMISSION_CLIP_ENTRY sce,
>   SUBMISSION_PERIOD sp,BATCH_TYPE bt
>   where sde.sub_perd_id=sp.sub_perd_id 
>   and sde.bpr_pk=bp.bpr_pk and sde.sts_pk=st.sts_pk
>   and sce.sde_pk=sde.sde_pk 
>   and bt.bat_pk =bp.bat_pk
>   group by bt.bat_pk, st.sts_pk;
> ```